# BibLaTeX + Biber finds too many citekeys

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biber

I am using TeXstudio to build PDFLaTeX files with biblatex+biber as backend.

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=numeric,citestyle=numeric-comp,hyperref,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
```

and then in the document section

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

TeXstudio should be properly setup to use biber as default (Option, Configure, Build, Deafult Bibilography Tool is Biber).

Now the problem: I tried adding 5 citations keys with \cite{}, however biber finds 9 citation keys

```
Process started: "C:/Users/lucam/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/biber.exe" "main"

INFO - This is Biber 2.19
INFO - Logfile is 'main.blg'
INFO - Reading 'main.bcf'
INFO - Found 9 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex file 'bibliography.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'bibliography.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Sorting list 'none/global//global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'none' and locale 'en-US'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
INFO - Writing 'main.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to main.bbl
Process exited normally
```

and I have no clue how to solve this issue (for context, there are over 70 items in the .bib file, so it is not simply printing out everything).

Any idea on how I could solve this problem?

EDIT: Here a minimal working example

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}               
\usepackage[english]{babel}         

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=numeric,citestyle=numeric-comp,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
    
\cite{amoretti:destroyingsuperconductivity}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

For this simple case it finds 5 citationkeys (1 is correct, the other 4 are the same extra 4 it adds when I try to run my thesis). In the .bib file, among other things, are the items found by biber. This first item is the desired one

```
@article{amoretti:destroyingsuperconductivity,
  title = {Destroying Superconductivity in Thin Films with an Electric Field},
  author = {Amoretti, Andrea and Brattan, Daniel K. and Magnoli, Nicodemo and Martinoia, Luca and Matthaiakakis, Ioannis and Solinas, Paolo},
  date = {2022-09-19},
  journaltitle = {Physical Review Research},
  shortjournal = {Phys. Rev. Research},
  volume = {4},
  number = {3},
  pages = {033211},
  publisher = {{American Physical Society}},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevResearch.4.033211},
  urldate = {2022-09-20},
  abstract = {}
}
```

but biber is also adding e.g.

```
@article{sogabe:positivemagnetoresistance,
  ids = {sogabe:positivemagnetoresistancea},
  title = {Positive Magnetoresistance Induced by Hydrodynamic Fluctuations in Chiral Media},
  author = {Sogabe, Noriyuki and Yamamoto, Naoki and Yin, Yi},
  date = {2021-09-21},
  journaltitle = {Journal of High Energy Physics},
  shortjournal = {J. High Energ. Phys.},
  volume = {2021},
  number = {9},
  pages = {131},
  issn = {1029-8479},
  doi = {10.1007/JHEP09(2021)131},
  urldate = {2022-06-27},
  langid = {english},
  keywords = {Anomalies in Field and String Theories,Effective Field Theories,Topological States of Matter}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you include a small example of code that can compile please along with example `.bib` entries? Probably difficult or impossible to help with just this information

Comment: Is bibliography.bib in the local directory or in your texmf tree? Maybe there's more than one file with this name?

Comment: In that minimal example with one citation, biber is finding 4 cite keys?

Comment: @musarithmia No, only one file in the same directory as "main.tex" and yes, the example has one citation in theory, but 5 in total appear in the bibliography.
I found that the problem seems to be in the "ids" attribute (which I have no idea what it is supposed to do), so I think the problem is now solved.

Comment: Can you show us the `.bcf` file of your MWE? It is probably too long to be included here, so please upload it to a text-sharing website such as https://gist.github.com/ or https://pastebin.com/. For comparison https://gist.github.com/moewew/3614884c3789107535c98ec49f777880 is what my system produces: only one `bcf:citekey`.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. If I combine your two entries in one bib, biblatex uses only one. `ids` allows to define alias key names (using the same as the main one, doesn't make much sense) .